# no match for ‘operator+=’ aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map called `assets` returned from a const function, I use a const_iterator to get a subset of the map like this:

```
std::map<int, Asset>::const_iterator start = assets.begin();
start += 5;
......
```

But I got error: `error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<int, Asset>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const int, Asset> >}’ and ‘int’)`

Comment: The duplicate is about `std::list`, but the issue is exactly the same: `std::map` has bidirectional operators, which don't support this type arithmetic operation. You need to increment them one step at a time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `std::map` iterators are BidirectionalIterators, not RandomAccessIterators - and hence support `operator++` and `operator--` but not `operator+=` and `operator-=`.

Use `std::advance(start, 5)` instead (bearing in mind that this will result in repeated invocation of `operator++`).

Comment: Note that std::advance will invoke operator+= instead if it's a random access iterator.