# No match for "operator-" on reverse_iterator for std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, stdmap

I have a `std::map`, and I am trying to compare all of the entries with all of the other entries in an efficient manner. My thought process was that I would have a nested loop with a starting point of the entry after the current one.

I have the following code as an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
  m["one"]    = "a";
  m["two"]    = "b";
  m["three"]  = "c";
  m["four"]   = "d";
  m["five"]   = "e";
  m["six"]    = "f";
  m["seven"]  = "g";

  for (auto outerIterator = m.begin(); outerIterator != m.end(); ++outerIterator)
  {
    std::cout << outerIterator->second << std::endl;

    for (auto innerIterator = outerIterator + 1; innerIterator != m.end(); ++innerIterator)
    {
      std::cout << " > " << innerIterator->second << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When trying this, I get the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’ and ‘int’)
    for (auto innerIterator = outerIterator + 1; innerIterator != m.end(); ++innerIterator)
                                            ^
```

Obviously, it does not like the way I tried to get to the next entry (I tried this based on a working example using `std::vector`). Is it possible to do what I am trying to do with just a `std::map`, or do I need to rethink my approach and choose a different was of storing my data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997584/no-match-for-operator-aka-std-rb-tree-const-iterator-stdmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map::iterator` is not a randomly accessed iterator, thus it does not have `operator+(int)`. You may work around the problem:

```
for (auto outerIterator = m.begin(); outerIterator != m.end(); )
{
    std::cout << outerIterator->second << std::endl;

    for (auto innerIterator = ++outerIterator; innerIterator != m.end(); ++innerIterator)
    {
      std::cout << " > " << innerIterator->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```